# Giving WordPress Its Own Directory when root is redirected to subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory, document-root

So I'm setting up a WP-site on web-server using a subfolder as root for the main-page, and I can't get it to work. The true root is locked, so I can't access that.

The original .htaccess & index.html file is located in ftp://ftp.example//web/
and I want to install my WP in ftp://ftp.example//web/wp.

First I **changed the the general settings** in WP to:

WordPress Address (URL): `http://www.example.com/wp`

Site Address (URL):      `http://www.example.com`

Then I **copied index.php and htaccess** to ftp://einstein.netureza.pt//web/
and **changed line 17 in index.php** to `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . 'wp/wp-blog-header.php' );` and **updated the permalinks in wp-admin**.

.htaccess now says:

```
## Default .htaccess file

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When I go to my url `http://www.example.com` I just get this error:

```
The strategy4change.eu page isn’t working

strategy4change.eu is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

However, visiting http://www.example.com/wp works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputations to comment. But I hope this is a valid answer:

You missed a forward slash:

```
require( __DIR__ . '/wp/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Comment: Oh my, that's just classical ;)
Cheers.